# Remote IIS administation options missing in Windows 8

Tags: iis, iis-8

I would like to remotely administer IIS on a couple of test servers from my Windows 8 Professional machine. However, the options to do so seem to be missing from IIS Manager.

[image]

My expectation is that there should be a few extra buttons in the area below **Connections**.

Is there an extra Windows component that I need to install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. I needed to install [IIS Manager for Remote Administration](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-manager).

[image]

The left-most button contains the options I was looking for.

[image]

Comment: Is this not included in the RSAT tools?